# Auto-suggest libraries for embedding json-schema described objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonschema

We're building an email templating feature into a platform. The objects and variables that users can insert into their emails are described by json-schema.

I figure we can't be the first to be doing this but google hasn't revealed much in the way of libraries that can help with this.

I'm thinking `ajv` to simply compile all the schemas (the schemas are in multiple files), but then in terms of turning that into UI, so far it seems like we're building from scratch.

Are there JS libraries available that can help with this?

We're using react on the front end.

Answer (score -1):

I am working on the same problem as well, the most famous library is [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) which published by mozilla, This is a great library using bootstrap.

There is another library called [react-schema-form](https://github.com/networknt/react-schema-form) which using material-ui right now.

But I want to use my own component lib, finally, I choose the [liform-react](https://github.com/Limenius/liform-react), which use the redux-form and ajv, The best part of it is that you can customize all the components in there. the only drawback for now is that you cannot customize the submit button, I just send a PR to the maintainer but they have not merged yet.

Hope these above can help you.

Comment: These are form builders, not autosuggest. We need something so that when a user is typing in a text box and wants to insert a variable from our schema, it is auto-suggested as they type.